# AXIOS: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: axios, auth0

I am using Auth0 and trying to make a patch/get request to `/v2/users/{id}` from `localhost:3000/profile` using axios. I am getting back the error in the title.

I have enabled the CORS in the dashboard for both `/` and `/profile` for `localhost:3000`.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000/profile'
    };

    axios.patch(
      `https://taustin.auth0.com/api/v2/users/${this.state.profile.sub}`,
      { user_metadata: this.state.items },
      headers
    );
```

I have tested on postman, so I know that the token works and that everything else works as well. It is some issue with `CORS` that I do not know how to fix.
I have also tried `{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`: `'*'}` and that did not work either.

Comment: is it just a typo in your post but you have "`https://taustin.auth0.com/api/vs/...", shouldn't that be " 'https://taustin.auth0.com/api/v2/users/${this.state.profile.sub}' and does the patch work in postman?

Comment: could you try doing a post instead of a patch? does that work?

Comment: I will try the post today , sorry long busy weekend. @kimcodes

Comment: @kimcodes that was a typo that I missed in my code as well. I am now getting a 401 error, which according to the api can be `Invalid token.` , `Client is not global.` , `Invalid signature received for JSON Web Token validation`.

Comment: I know this is a year later, but I've run into the same issue. 401. And the answer is audience is set to the api the application uses and not the management api. Auth0's answer to this is to create a logical API and then use the audience as a "common" audience to both. It makes no sense when the token is generated from their application to begin with.